# Authorization required to install jzos batch launcher?

Tags: java, authorization, zos

We are trying to install the JZOS Batch Launcher. The function consists of three pieces: a load module that must be put into a z/OS PDSE, a sample start proc that can be tailored and put into an appropriate PROCLIB, and sample JCL that can be tailored and put into an appropriate SAMPLIB.

On submitting the job we are getting return code=0101. Below are the trace details which we are getting in the job:

```
  Output from DD:STDENV config shell script:
 waiting for child shell process to complete
  waitChild()
 child shell process exited with exit code 0
  waitChild()
 Child shell process exited without printing environment; //STDENV should not contain 'exit'
  adoptEnvironment()
  run()
  cleanup()
 JZOS batch launcher elapsed time=0 seconds, cpu time=0.040000 seconds
 JZOS batch launcher failed, return code=101
 cleanup()
 ~JzosVM()
 ~JzosVM()
```

After looking this up and reading more,we then tried to run the job with superuser access and the job ran fine. So we need to know what privileges we require without being a superuser which will enable us to run the job successfully.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/ajvc0120.pdf), return code 101 is RC_CONFIG_ERR.  The documentation further suggests looking at SYSOUT for further information.  As this is a vendor supported product I suggest contacting your IBM representative for further assistance.

Comment: If you need the "big guns", you can trace every UNIX Services call with GTF by selecting the SYSOMVS trace events...this will show you the function and return codes (ERRNO/ERRNO2) that are at the root of your problem, and you can usually figure it out from there.